# are fuses kiln safe?

Tags: heat

im wondering of car fuses (the cylindrical kind) would be able to be put in a kiln and come out not melted. i need to know for a clay project. the sooner i know the better. thanks for your time. I have looked into how hot a kiln gets compared to an air only torch and the torch is hotter. so i ytested a few using a propane torch and they didn't take much damage. however my clay teachers want to put them in the kiln cause she thinks the glass will melt.

Comment: There are very few metals that will withstand the temperatures found in a kiln. I really enjoyed my pottery classes and hope to set up a home kiln one day. But the temperatures involved are enormous. They can get near to \$1300\:^\circ\textrm{C}\$ with a #10 cone for firing glazes! Copper runs almost like water then.  If you made your fuses using Iridium, for example, you'd be fine. But that's pretty much only found on asteroids. You can use platinum fusing. Not sure if anyone is making that, but I believe it could withstand the temps involved. Of course, there is still the casing as a worry.

Comment: Even if the glass won't melt, at least the glass will bend. What temperature will you set the kiln?

Comment: Even if the torch is hotter, you still aren't holding it against the piece for hours.

Comment: Is your shift key broken?

Comment: Why would you put a fuse through a kiln? Are there electronics attached that will also pass through the kiln? If so, I'd worry about those before the fuse...

Comment: i don't what they are made of. i don't need to function thy are more for astetics

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with the fuses.

If you want them to carry, and break at, their respective currents, then forget it. Fuses rely on the melting of wire inside, and changing the temperature significantly will change the amount of heat needed to open the fuse.

If you want the fuse to be incorporated as part of an art work, then you'll need to put it in a kiln and try it. The temperatures are so extreme, depending on the setting able to melt copper, glass etc, that it will depend on the particular construction of the fuse and the specific temperature you get to. Unless you get it to a nice uniform glowing heat and hold it there for minutes, testing with a gas torch is unlikely to be a good predictor of what happens in the kiln.

Comment: i want them for astetics